# Считывание json и фильтрация данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Я хочу написать скрипт на Python3 для того, чтобы он автоматически давал мне id из дампа, есть загвоздка, в дампе все строки имеют следующий вид:

```
[{"id": 731590121, "first_name": "Ivan", "last_name": "Ivanovich", "user": "PutinVodkaBalalayka", "phone": "788005553535", "is_bot": false}, {"id": 719381938, ... "is_bot": false]
```

Загвоздка в том, что мне нужен лишь id (для взаимодействия с api), если будете делать очистку файла, то можете дать мне пример с выводом результатов (в реальном времени по ходу работы скрипта) в консоль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dpath`](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/)

```py
from dpath import util

d = [{'id': 731590121, 'first_name': 'Ivan', 'last_name': 'Ivanovich', 'user': 'PutinVodkaBalalayka', 'phone': '788005553535', 'is_bot': False}, {'id': 719381938, 'is_bot': False}]

print(util.values(d, "*/id"))
# [731590121, 719381938]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

string = '[{"id": 731590121, "first_name": "Ivan", "last_name": "Ivanovich", "user": "PutinVodkaBalalayka", "phone": "788005553535", "is_bot": false}, {"id": 719381938, ... "is_bot": false]'

id_list = re.findall('(?:"id": )(\d+)', string)

print(id_list)
```

Comment: А как-то считывать файлы json с использованием этого фильтра можно?

Comment: @Vorobuska в питоне есть [модуль для работы с json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: Я знаю, но либо я слепой, либо в документации не сказано как его считывать

Comment: @Vorobuska [из файла](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), [из строки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю